# How to design an inductor for the output of a low-pass filter for a 10 kVA sinusoidal UPS

Tags: power, filter, low-pass, ups, saturation

The problem is that I have a 10 kVA sinusoidal UPS to repair and after replacing all the IGBTs and other components, I noticed that the low-pass filter output inductor is getting very hot at around 120°C, so much so that the PCB is a little burned. I checked the LC filter capacitors and found one of them with a value of 8.8 µF instead of the 20 µF marked on the box itself. I changed the capacitors, but it continues to heat up a lot. Could anyone help with this?

I tried to find information about the LC filter on the web, but I couldn't. All the information I can find talks about how to calculate the LC filter, but it doesn't mention how to calculate the inductor dimensions as a function of power. Not to mention that the calculations do not coincide with the original values of the UPS capacitors, inductors and SPWM frequency. I imagine that the heating of the inductors is due to their saturation due to being out of tune. I know that it is always a compromise to be considered when calculating these inductors, due to the inherent problems. I ask how do I check if the inductors in question are within the minimum requirements required for the function?

Below are the details about UPS:

1. Single-phase output = 220 VAC
2. Output frequency = 60 Hz
3. SPWM Frequency = 18 kHz
4. Output low-pass LC filter capacitance = 2 x 20 µF in parallel = 40 µF total (250 V MKP type)
5. Low pass LC output inductors = 2 x 630 µH each in parallel = 315 µH total
6. Output power = 10 kVA

**Below are the responses from the people who are helping:**

**Replying to GrayBeard**: This UPS operates on a continuous basis; The load percentage under the problem conditions is 0%, no load; The inductor in question is under forced ventilation without any obstruction and yet with a temperature of 120°C. Ambient temperature of 32°C; The mentioned capacitors constitute the output LC filter only.

**Replying to Tim Willian:** The inductors apparently have normal wires, however the insulation with polyester tape between the ferrite toroid and the coil is crumbling due to higher than normal heating;  The inductor are an uncoated, toroidal-shaped core with a brown color. The dimensions are, OD = 50.7, ID = 32 and high of 24.7 millimeters. It has 91 turns with double wire of 16 AWG. There are two inductors in parallel of 630uH each, totaling 315uH. The value found of 630uH was with the inductor outside the circuit in its current state and at room temperature. The output voltage of this LC filter is 220Vac, the nominal frequency is 60Hz and the SPWM frequency is 18Khz.

**Replying to GreyBeard:** Could you please elaborate further on your comment?

**Replying to Russell MacMahon:** Yes, the inductor in question is under forced ventilation with an ambient temperature of 32°C; Sorry, I don't know what "cirr metal" is; I agree with the fact that iron powder core degrade as a function of temperature but I have no way of knowing which type it is.

Thank you for all attention.

Renato.

Comment: `120°C` under what operation regime? What percentage of nominal load, what shape of output current? Enclosure closed, no venting obstructed, all fans working? Environment temperature? There are different causes for losses in inductors. Are there capacitors to both "input"&"output" of the inductors?

Comment: What do they look like? Darkened from the heat perhaps, but what is wire size, number of strands, etc., core color(s), dimensions? Also, is 630uH measured on the aged part? What V, F was it measured at?

Comment: (The trivial part should be establishing temperature rise@10 kVA/220 V(/2 for one of two parallel inductors…) (IGBT, but not 2***3***0 V?!))

Comment: Question can be reopened with more information. Please answer questions people have asked where known.|| Micrometals have design guides that will allow you to design for that requirement including temperature. || Does it have good airflow? Is it metal or ? Powdered iron cores will degrade rapidly with excess heat.

Comment: The answers are in the body of the question, as the number of characters in the answer field has exceeded.

Comment: One more thing: could you take photos of the parts and boards in question? Also, if possible, could you find photos of new or replacement boards? Perhaps the core can be better recognized in that state. || I think you misunderstood a part of my question: a meter measures inductance by applying some voltage or current and measuring the impedance, and we need to know what frequency and amplitude this is done at. If it's not on the display, it's probably in the manual, or you can say what instrument (at what settings) you used to measure it.

Comment: WHY WAS THIS DOWNVOTED? Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: `toroidal-shaped core with a brown color` micrometal offers iron powder cores, back in the day the material for 18 kHz would have been [26](https://www.micrometals.com/products/materials/pc/) - yellow on delivery. They also offer [high temperature core materials with brown part of the colour code](https://www.micrometals.com/products/materials/200c/). (Any temperature sensitive components nearby?) If the dimensions quoted are core dimensions rather than overall, they might be darkened [T201-26](https://datasheets.micrometals.com/T201-26-DataSheet.pdf) cores.

Comment: You state you found inductance `outside the circuit`: 10 kVA/220 V/2 are some 22.7 A. Monitor temperature rise using a DC lab supply set to, say, 20 A, *with decent air flow*.